# Browser hangs when i call this.$router.push()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js, I have a button that triggers this.$router.push({ name: 'profile-info' })

// router.js

```
...
export const routerOptions = {
  mode: 'history',
  base: decodeURI('/'),
  linkActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-active',
  linkExactActiveClass: 'nuxt-link-exact-active',
  scrollBehavior,

  routes: [{
    path: "/profile",
    component: _21560a2a,
    name: "profile",
    children: [{
      path: "info",
      component: _7cf67dd8,
      name: "profile-info"
    }]
  }, {
    path: "/",
    component: _4ca319da,
    name: "index"
  }],

  fallback: false
}
...
```

so when i trigger the this.$router.push, the browser just hangs and i have to forcefully close the browser, because i cant close the tab.

In chrome dev tools, in the network tab, the js files of the page is just pending and then times out

[image]

Comment: Are you using `beforeEach` navigation guard, or any redirects?  Could be a redirect loop.

Comment: so thanks for the idea of redirect loop, i looked through code which could affect any redirection, and i saw i was using fetch hook and redirecting from there, I was not handling the redirection properly. this question in now answered, thanks!

Comment: Nice, you're welcome

Comment: can you show us the solution